# link an image position to another image using css

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to position my image of a butterfly on to the image of flowers

I am able to do it if there is no container elements with margins or padding in %, however if the images is in a responsive website position: absolute; does not produce the right results.
below is the code I'm working with 
i have changed the images to online hosted ones and added the css from the external file in the html
please click on step 4 and see that the butterfly is not linked to image of the daisies.

how can I make it so that no matter what the size of the window is, the image of the butterfly stays related to the daisies.

thank you

i have also made a https://jsfiddle.net/aLq8j6r1/ for it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Week 3 Classwork</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="week3style.css"> 
     <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: beige;
        }

        #topNavBar ul{
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0 15%;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: black;
            overflow: hidden;




        }


        #topNavBar a{
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
             padding: 16px;
            display: block;

        }

        #topNavBar li{
            float: left;
            background-color: black;



        }

        #topNavBar li:hover{
        background-color: red;
        }

        .block{
            margin: 3% 15%;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: white;

        }

         .displayNone{
             display: none;
         }
    </style>
</head>


<body>

    <div id="topNavBar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="classwork.html">Classwork Week 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="homework.html">Homework Week 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="../index.html">Homepage</a></li>


        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="mainSection">
       <!-- in block there is everything -->
        <div class="block">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;">ClassWork week 3</h1>

            <div id="firstExercise">
                <h2>Animation With HTML 5</h2>

                <div id="buttons">
                    <button onclick="showStep1()">step1</button>
                    <button onclick="showStep2()">step2</button>
                    <button onclick="showStep3()">step3</button>
                    <button onclick="showStep4()">step4</button>
                    <button onclick="showStep5()">step5</button>
                    <button onclick="showStep6()">step6</button>
                </div>
                <div id="step1Div" style="width: 580px;height: 50px; border: solid 4px black;">
                    <div id="elem" style="position: relative; width: 20px; height: 50px;background-color: aquamarine;"></div>
                        <script>
                        //onclick the elem it move right 
                        var elem = document.getElementById("elem");
                        var left = 0;
                        var move;
                            elem.onclick=function myfunction(){
                             move =setInterval(movElem, 10);

                        }

                        function movElem(){
                        if(left>400){
                         clearInterval(move);   
                        }
                         elem.style.left= left++ +"px";

                        }
                        </script>
                </div>

                   <!-- box -->
                <div id="step2Div" class="displayNone"   style="width: 580px;height: 580px; border: solid 4px black;">
                    <!-- blue move element -->
                    <div id="elemStep2" style="position: relative; width: 20px; height: 50px;background-color: aquamarine;"></div>



                    <script>
                    //on click - move right and down  till 400px right then move left

                        //how to move ? -setInterval

                        //use long names 

                        //pseudo code:
                        //var nameofelement = get elemebt by id elemstep2;
                        var elemStep2 = document.getElementById("elemStep2");
                        //nameofelement.onclick: do following slowly:
                        elemStep2.onclick=function myOnclickFunctionStep2(){
                          // (left increase to 400
                            var iStep2=0;
                            //the following line will start to move the element to right and down
                            var vstep2Move1=setInterval(Step2Move1,10);
                            function Step2Move1(){
                            elemStep2.style.left= iStep2++ +"px";

                             elemStep2.style.top= iStep2/2 +"px"; 
                             //following will check if 400 is reached and if reached will stop movement and start movement 2
                                //stop and start move left till left is 20px 
                            if(iStep2>400){
                                clearInterval(vstep2Move1);                   vstep2Move2=setInterval(fStep2Move2,10);                  
                            }




                            };
                            var gStep2=400;
                            var vstep2Move2;
                            function fStep2Move2(){
                                elemStep2.style.left= gStep2-- +"px";
                                if(gStep2<20){
                                    clearInterval(vstep2Move2); 
                                }
                            }
                            //

                        };


                    </script>

                </div>



                <!-- box -->
                <div id="step3Div" class="displayNone" style="width: 580px;height: 580px; border: solid 4px black;">
                    <!-- blue  element -->
                    <div id="elemStep3" style="position: relative; width: 20px; height: 50px;background-color: aquamarine;"></div>

                    <script>
                    var elemStep3= document.getElementById("elemStep3");
                        var iStep3=0;
                        var gStep3 =400;
                        var hStep3 =20;
                        var vStep3Move1;
                        var vStep3Move2;
                        var vStep3Move3;

                        elemStep3.onclick=function onclickFunctionStep3(){
                          vStep3Move1= setInterval(fStep3Move1,10);
                            function fStep3Move1(){
                                //move it 
                                elemStep3.style.left= iStep3++ +"px";
                                elemStep3.style.top= iStep3/2 +"px";


                                //if statement for stopping vStep3Move1
                                if(iStep3>400){
                                    clearInterval(vStep3Move1);
                                    vStep3Move2 = setInterval(fStep3Move2,10);
                                }

                            }
                            function fStep3Move2(){
                                elemStep3.style.left= gStep3-- +"px";
                                if(gStep3<20){
                                    clearInterval(vStep3Move2);
                                   vStep3Move3= setInterval(fStep3Move3,10);
                                }
                            }
                            function fStep3Move3(){
                                elemStep3.style.left= hStep3++ +"px";
                                elemStep3.style.top= (hStep3/2)+200 +"px";
                                if(hStep3> 400){
                                    clearInterval(vStep3Move3);
                                }
                            }
                        };

                    </script>

                </div>

                <div class="displayNone" id="step4Div">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/XoZr6dM.jpg" alt="" style="position: relative;width: 580px;" >
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2s1zwDb.gif

 1. List item

" alt="" style="position:absolute;   top: 0; left: 0;">
                </div>
                <div class="displayNone" id="step5Div">step5</div>
                <div class="displayNone" id="step6Div">step6</div>





                <style>
                    .displayNone{
                        display: none;
                    }

                </style>
                <script>

                    var step1Div = document.getElementById("step1Div");
                    var step2Div = document.getElementById("step2Div");
                    var step3Div = document.getElementById("step3Div");
                    var step4Div = document.getElementById("step4Div");
                    var step5Div = document.getElementById("step5Div");
                    var step6Div = document.getElementById("step6Div");


                    function showStep1(){
                        step1Div.classList.remove("displayNone");
                        step2Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step3Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step4Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step5Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step6Div.classList.add("displayNone");

                    }
                    function showStep2(){
                        step2Div.classList.remove("displayNone");
                        step1Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step3Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step4Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step5Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step6Div.classList.add("displayNone");

                    }
                    function showStep3(){
                        step3Div.classList.remove("displayNone");
                        step2Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step1Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step4Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step5Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step6Div.classList.add("displayNone");

                    }
                    function showStep4(){
                        step4Div.classList.remove("displayNone");
                        step2Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step3Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step1Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step5Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step6Div.classList.add("displayNone");

                    }
                    function showStep5(){
                        step5Div.classList.remove("displayNone");
                        step2Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step3Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step4Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step1Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step6Div.classList.add("displayNone");

                    }
                    function showStep6(){
                        step6Div.classList.remove("displayNone");
                        step2Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step3Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step4Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step5Div.classList.add("displayNone");
                        step1Div.classList.add("displayNone");

                    }

                </script>


            </div>















            <div id="secondExercise">    
                <h2>OOP Exercise/Demo</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="thirdExercise">   
                <h2>Javascript slideshow</h2>
            </div> 
            <div id="fourthExercise">
                <h2>Menu</h2>
            </div>    
        </div><!-- block ends -->


    </div><!-- main sedction ends -->




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, an absolute positioned element stays relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

So you should add `position:relative` to it's parent. In your case `#step4Div` . Then position it how you want. Using `top` and `left` and other styles.

My suggestion is you don't use inline styles but write them in the css.

I won't get into the javascript code which **definitely** needs some refactoring. Too many lines of code that are overkill.

```js
   var step1Div = document.getElementById("step1Div");
        var step2Div = document.getElementById("step2Div");
        var step3Div = document.getElementById("step3Div");
        var step4Div = document.getElementById("step4Div");
        var step5Div = document.getElementById("step5Div");
        var step6Div = document.getElementById("step6Div");


        function showStep1() {
          step1Div.classList.remove("displayNone");
          step2Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step3Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step4Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step5Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step6Div.classList.add("displayNone");

        }

        function showStep2() {
          step2Div.classList.remove("displayNone");
          step1Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step3Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step4Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step5Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step6Div.classList.add("displayNone");

        }

        function showStep3() {
          step3Div.classList.remove("displayNone");
          step2Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step1Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step4Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step5Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step6Div.classList.add("displayNone");

        }

        function showStep4() {
          step4Div.classList.remove("displayNone");
          step2Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step3Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step1Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step5Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step6Div.classList.add("displayNone");

        }

        function showStep5() {
          step5Div.classList.remove("displayNone");
          step2Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step3Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step4Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step1Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step6Div.classList.add("displayNone");

        }

        function showStep6() {
          step6Div.classList.remove("displayNone");
          step2Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step3Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step4Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step5Div.classList.add("displayNone");
          step1Div.classList.add("displayNone");

        }
```

```css
 body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background-color: beige;
 }

 #topNavBar ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   padding: 0 15%;
   margin: 0;
   background-color: black;
   overflow: hidden;
 }

 #topNavBar a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
   padding: 16px;
   display: block;
 }

 #topNavBar li {
   float: left;
   background-color: black;
 }

 #topNavBar li:hover {
   background-color: red;
 }

 .block {
   margin: 3% 15%;
   padding: 10px;
   background-color: white;
 }

 .displayNone {
   display: none;
 }
 #step4Div {
    position: relative;
 }
```

```html
<div id="topNavBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="classwork.html">Classwork Week 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="homework.html">Homework Week 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="../index.html">Homepage</a></li>


  </ul>
</div>

<div id="mainSection">
  <!-- in block there is everything -->
  <div class="block">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">ClassWork week 3</h1>

    <div id="firstExercise">
      <h2>Animation With HTML 5</h2>

      <div id="buttons">
        <button onclick="showStep1()">step1</button>
        <button onclick="showStep2()">step2</button>
        <button onclick="showStep3()">step3</button>
        <button onclick="showStep4()">step4</button>
        <button onclick="showStep5()">step5</button>
        <button onclick="showStep6()">step6</button>
      </div>
      <div id="step1Div" style="width: 580px;height: 50px; border: solid 4px black;">
        <div id="elem" style="position: relative; width: 20px; height: 50px;background-color: aquamarine;"></div>
        <script>
          //onclick the elem it move right 
          var elem = document.getElementById("elem");
          var left = 0;
          var move;
          elem.onclick = function myfunction() {
            move = setInterval(movElem, 10);

          }

          function movElem() {
            if (left > 400) {
              clearInterval(move);
            }
            elem.style.left = left++ + "px";

          }

        </script>
      </div>

      <!-- box -->
      <div id="step2Div" class="displayNone" style="width: 580px;height: 580px; border: solid 4px black;">
        <!-- blue move element -->
        <div id="elemStep2" style="position: relative; width: 20px; height: 50px;background-color: aquamarine;"></div>



        <script>
          //on click - move right and down  till 400px right then move left

          //how to move ? -setInterval

          //use long names 

          //pseudo code:
          //var nameofelement = get elemebt by id elemstep2;
          var elemStep2 = document.getElementById("elemStep2");
          //nameofelement.onclick: do following slowly:
          elemStep2.onclick = function myOnclickFunctionStep2() {
            // (left increase to 400
            var iStep2 = 0;
            //the following line will start to move the element to right and down
            var vstep2Move1 = setInterval(Step2Move1, 10);

            function Step2Move1() {
              elemStep2.style.left = iStep2++ + "px";

              elemStep2.style.top = iStep2 / 2 + "px";
              //following will check if 400 is reached and if reached will stop movement and start movement 2
              //stop and start move left till left is 20px 
              if (iStep2 > 400) {
                clearInterval(vstep2Move1);
                vstep2Move2 = setInterval(fStep2Move2, 10);
              }




            };
            var gStep2 = 400;
            var vstep2Move2;

            function fStep2Move2() {
              elemStep2.style.left = gStep2-- + "px";
              if (gStep2 < 20) {
                clearInterval(vstep2Move2);
              }
            }
            //

          };

        </script>

      </div>



      <!-- box -->
      <div id="step3Div" class="displayNone" style="width: 580px;height: 580px; border: solid 4px black;">
        <!-- blue  element -->
        <div id="elemStep3" style="position: relative; width: 20px; height: 50px;background-color: aquamarine;"></div>

        <script>
          var elemStep3 = document.getElementById("elemStep3");
          var iStep3 = 0;
          var gStep3 = 400;
          var hStep3 = 20;
          var vStep3Move1;
          var vStep3Move2;
          var vStep3Move3;

          elemStep3.onclick = function onclickFunctionStep3() {
            vStep3Move1 = setInterval(fStep3Move1, 10);

            function fStep3Move1() {
              //move it 
              elemStep3.style.left = iStep3++ + "px";
              elemStep3.style.top = iStep3 / 2 + "px";


              //if statement for stopping vStep3Move1
              if (iStep3 > 400) {
                clearInterval(vStep3Move1);
                vStep3Move2 = setInterval(fStep3Move2, 10);
              }

            }

            function fStep3Move2() {
              elemStep3.style.left = gStep3-- + "px";
              if (gStep3 < 20) {
                clearInterval(vStep3Move2);
                vStep3Move3 = setInterval(fStep3Move3, 10);
              }
            }

            function fStep3Move3() {
              elemStep3.style.left = hStep3++ + "px";
              elemStep3.style.top = (hStep3 / 2) + 200 + "px";
              if (hStep3 > 400) {
                clearInterval(vStep3Move3);
              }
            }
          };

        </script>

      </div>

      <div class="displayNone" id="step4Div">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/XoZr6dM.jpg" alt="" style="position: relative;width: 580px;">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2s1zwDb.gif

 1. List item

" alt="" style="position:absolute;   top: 0; left: 0;">
      </div>
      <div class="displayNone" id="step5Div">step5</div>
      <div class="displayNone" id="step6Div">step6</div>

    </div>

    <div id="secondExercise">
      <h2>OOP Exercise/Demo</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="thirdExercise">
      <h2>Javascript slideshow</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="fourthExercise">
      <h2>Menu</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- block ends -->


</div>
<!-- main sedction ends -->
```

Answer (score -1):

To explain a bit:

`absolute` explicitly makes the styled element positioned absolutely compared to the closest parent that is *also* explicitly positioned.

The butterfly you have correctly positioned `absolute` because it needs to be positioned on top of the flowers. However it was absolute compared to the closest parent ie the `body` (it looks like).

Adding `relative` makes the styled element stay where it would have been without styling `relative`, however the `relative` element now forms the closest explicitly positioned parent.

`<div class="displayNone" id="step4Div" style="position:relative">`